# Some CSS problems to vertically extend the content of a div until the end of its container in a layout

Tags: html, css, layout, xhtml

I am creating an HTML\CSS tabless layout starting from a psd file and I am having a litle problem.

This is my final result that I would obtain:

[image]

and this is my HTML\CSS result: http://onofri.org/example/WebTemplate/

As you can see I have some problem with the left sidebar because the last blue box (the **#c div**) does not extend vertically to the end of the **#container div** and so don't match with the footer background immage.

The pnly "solution" that I have found (but this is not a correct solution) is to increase the value of the **min-height* property of the **#c div** of my sidebare. For example if I increase this value from the original 234px to 334px it seems to work well.

But this is not a real solution because if the amount of content change of the page change this problem occurs again.

How can I solve? What can I do to extend the height of the #c div until the end of its container

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: First of all, you have two different `height` attributes, get rid of one of them.

Comment: You have lots of code that looks thrown together. For example under `#sidebar` you have three different `box-shadow` attributes, it's also floating left when it would be easier to float right. 

Not related to your original post but thought I should let you know.

Comment: @BeatAlex I think that isindifferent using the float: right instead the float: left. And, for the #sidebar div I have only one box-shadow (the others are commented...)

Comment: The height is being affected by the content on the left. Even if there is no content, the `<hr>` needs to be removed for it to hit the footer.

Comment: @BeatAlex I have removed the <hr> tags from the index.html file but I obtain no result, have I to do some others change in my code? Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little trick I use sometimes:

What you need to do is have both the #content and #sidebar divs within a container div. You tell that container div to have a class of "clearfix" and it will stretch itself to be the height of the tallest column. You can then give the container div a background image if you want to make the background of each column look like it stretches the whole length.

For example, a 1px high repeating background like this might work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W84Xa.jpg

THE CSS:

```
.clearfix:after{
content:”.”;
display:block;
clear:both;
visibility:hidden;
line-height:0;
height:0;}

.clearfix{
display:inline-block;
}

html[xmls].clearfix{
display:block;
}

*html.clearfix{
height:1%;
}

#container{
width:770px;
}

#content{
width:542px;
float:left;
}

#sidebar{
width:228px;
float:left;
}
```

THE HTML:

```
<div id="container" class="clearfix" >

<div id="content">
Content Div Text
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
Sidebar Div Text
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: mmm I don't know if this is a good solution for me because for the shadow I don't use a background immage but the CSS3 box-shadow tag